# GridLayout/BorderLayout Not Working

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, border-layout

I need to make a program that ends up looking like this:

[image]

My code so far is what's posted and I can't seem to wrap my head around how to make this look exactly like the image I provided. I just don't really know what else I can do, I've tried looking around for solutions, but I can't manage to combine that information with this to make it all work together.

So, I hope somebody else can help me here, it'd be greatly appreciated! :D

```
import java.awt.*;     // Needed for BorderLayout class  
import javax.swing.*;  // Needed for Swing classes  

/** 
   This class demonstrates how JPanels can be nested 
   inside each region of a content pane governed by 
   a BorderLayout manager. 
*/  

public class BorderPanelWindow extends JFrame  
{  
   /** 
      Constructor 
   */  

   public BorderPanelWindow()  
   {  
      // Set the title bar text.  
      setTitle("Border Layout");  

      // Specify an action for the close button.  
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  

      // Add a BorderLayout manager to the content pane.  
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());  

      // Create five panels.  
      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();  
      JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();  
      JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();  
      JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();  
      panel4.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));  
      JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();  
      panel5.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));  
      JPanel panel6 = new JPanel();  
      JPanel panel7 = new JPanel();  
      JPanel panel8 = new JPanel();  
      JPanel panel9 = new JPanel();  
      JPanel panel10 = new JPanel();  


      // Create five buttons.  
      JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");  
      JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");  
      JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");  
      JButton button4 = new JButton("Button 4");  
      JButton button5 = new JButton("Button 5");  
      JButton button6 = new JButton("Button 6");  
      JButton button7 = new JButton("Button 7");  
      JButton button8 = new JButton("Button 8");  
      JButton button9 = new JButton("Button 9");  
      JButton button10 = new JButton("Button 10");  

      //Add buttons to panel4  
      panel4.add(button1);  
      panel4.add(button2);  
      panel4.add(button3);  
      panel4.add(button4);  
      panel4.add(button5);  
      panel4.add(button6);  


      // Add the buttons to the panels.  
      panel7.add(button7);  
      panel8.add(button8);  
      panel9.add(button9);  
      panel10.add(button10);  

      // Add the five panels to the content pane.  
      add(panel7, BorderLayout.NORTH);  
      add(panel8, BorderLayout.SOUTH);  
      add(panel9, BorderLayout.EAST);  
      add(panel4, BorderLayout.WEST);  
      //add(panel10, BorderLayout.WEST);  
      add(panel5, BorderLayout.CENTER);  

      // Pack and display the window.  
      pack();  
      setVisible(true);  
   }  

   /** 
      The main method creates an instance of the 
      BorderPanelWindow class, causing it to display 
      its window. 
   */  

   public static void main(String[] args)  
   {  
      new BorderPanelWindow();  
   }  
}
```

### Update

So this is what I have so far in what I think an answer suggested me to do. Like I said I can't see my panel4 when I have button 10 on there as well, I'm sure it's something I'm just not seeing but still.

```
import java.awt.*;     // Needed for BorderLayout class
import javax.swing.*;  // Needed for Swing classes

/**
   This class demonstrates how JPanels can be nested
   inside each region of a content pane governed by
   a BorderLayout manager.
*/

public class BorderPanelWindow extends JFrame
{
   /**
      Constructor
   */

   public BorderPanelWindow()
   {
      // Set the title bar text.
      setTitle("Border Layout");

      // Specify an action for the close button.
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      // Add a BorderLayout manager to the content pane.
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      // Create five panels.
      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
      JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
      JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
      JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
      panel4.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
      JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();
      panel5.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
      JPanel panel6 = new JPanel();
      JPanel panel7 = new JPanel();
      JPanel panel8 = new JPanel();
      JPanel panel9 = new JPanel();
      JPanel panel10 = new JPanel();


      // Create five buttons.
      JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
      JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
      JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
      JButton button4 = new JButton("Button 4");
      JButton button5 = new JButton("Button 5");
      JButton button6 = new JButton("Button 6");
      JButton button7 = new JButton("Button 7");
      JButton button8 = new JButton("Button 8");
      JButton button9 = new JButton("Button 9");
      JButton button10 = new JButton("Button 10");
      JButton button11 = new JButton("Button 11");
      JButton button12 = new JButton("Button 12");
      JButton button13 = new JButton("Button 13");
      JButton button14 = new JButton("Button 14");
      JButton button15 = new JButton("Button 15");
      JButton button16 = new JButton("Button 16");
      JButton button17 = new JButton("Button 17");
      JButton button18 = new JButton("Button 18");

      //Add buttons to panel4
      panel4.add(button1);
      panel4.add(button2);
      panel4.add(button3);
      panel4.add(button4);
      panel4.add(button5);
      panel4.add(button6);

      //Add buttons to panel5
      panel5.add(button11);
      panel5.add(button12);
      panel5.add(button13);
      panel5.add(button14);
      panel5.add(button15);
      panel5.add(button16);
      panel5.add(button17);
      panel5.add(button18);


      // Add the buttons to the panels.
      panel7.add(button7);
      panel8.add(button8);
      panel9.add(button9);
      panel10.add(button10);

      // Add the five panels to the content pane.
      add(panel7, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(panel8, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      add(panel9, BorderLayout.EAST);
      add(panel4, BorderLayout.WEST);
      add(panel10, BorderLayout.WEST);
      add(panel5, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      // Pack and display the window.
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   /**
      The main method creates an instance of the
      BorderPanelWindow class, causing it to display
      its window.
   */

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      new BorderPanelWindow();
   }
}
```

### Update2

So now I polished it up a little bit and tried to do what you said but now it looks even worse so there's gotta be something I'm just not getting entirely lol. Hopefully you can see my mistake.

```
import java.awt.*;     // Needed for BorderLayout class
import javax.swing.*;  // Needed for Swing classes

/**
   This class demonstrates how JPanels can be nested
   inside each region of a content pane governed by
   a BorderLayout manager.
*/

public class BorderPanelWindow extends JFrame
{
   /**
      Constructor
   */

   public BorderPanelWindow()
   {
      // Set the title bar text.
      setTitle("Border Layout");

      // Specify an action for the close button.
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      // Add a BorderLayout manager to the content pane.
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      // Create five panels.
      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
      panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
      JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
      panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
      JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
      panel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
      panel4.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));


      // Create five buttons.
      JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
      JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
      JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
      JButton button4 = new JButton("Button 4");
      JButton button5 = new JButton("Button 5");
      JButton button6 = new JButton("Button 6");
      JButton button7 = new JButton("Button 7");
      JButton button8 = new JButton("Button 8");
      JButton button9 = new JButton("Button 9");
      JButton button10 = new JButton("Button 10");
      JButton button11 = new JButton("Button 11");
      JButton button12 = new JButton("Button 12");
      JButton button13 = new JButton("Button 13");
      JButton button14 = new JButton("Button 14");
      JButton button15 = new JButton("Button 15");
      JButton button16 = new JButton("Button 16");
      JButton button17 = new JButton("Button 17");
      JButton button18 = new JButton("Button 18");

      //Add buttons to panel1
      panel1.add(button1);
      panel1.add(button2);
      panel1.add(button3);
      panel1.add(button4);
      panel1.add(button5);
      panel1.add(button6);

      //Add buttons to panel2



      //Add the buttons to panel3
      panel3.add(button7);
      panel3.add(button8);
      panel3.add(button9);
      panel3.add(button10);

      //Add the buttons to panel4
      panel4.add(button11);
      panel4.add(button12);
      panel4.add(button13);
      panel4.add(button14);
      panel4.add(button15);
      panel4.add(button16);
      panel4.add(button17);
      panel4.add(button18);

      // Add the five panels to the content pane.
      add(panel1, BorderLayout.WEST);
      add(panel2, BorderLayout.EAST);
      add(panel3, BorderLayout.EAST);
      add(panel4, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      // Pack and display the window.
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   /**
      The main method creates an instance of the
      BorderPanelWindow class, causing it to display
      its window.
   */

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      new BorderPanelWindow();
   }
}
```

### Update3

Okay, I'm a little further now the big issue is that buttons 11-18 aren't coming up in the middle of buttons 7-10.

```
import java.awt.*;     // Needed for BorderLayout class
import javax.swing.*;  // Needed for Swing classes

/**
   This class demonstrates how JPanels can be nested
   inside each region of a content pane governed by
   a BorderLayout manager.
*/

public class BorderPanelWindow extends JFrame
{
   /**
      Constructor
   */

   public BorderPanelWindow()
   {
      // Set the title bar text.
      setTitle("Border Layout");

      // Specify an action for the close button.
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      // Add a BorderLayout manager to the content pane.
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      // Create five panels.
      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
      panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
      JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
      panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));
      JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
      panel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
      panel4.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));


      // Create five buttons.
      JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
      JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
      JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
      JButton button4 = new JButton("Button 4");
      JButton button5 = new JButton("Button 5");
      JButton button6 = new JButton("Button 6");
      JButton button7 = new JButton("Button 7");
      JButton button8 = new JButton("Button 8");
      JButton button9 = new JButton("Button 9");
      JButton button10 = new JButton("Button 10");
      JButton button11 = new JButton("Button 11");
      JButton button12 = new JButton("Button 12");
      JButton button13 = new JButton("Button 13");
      JButton button14 = new JButton("Button 14");
      JButton button15 = new JButton("Button 15");
      JButton button16 = new JButton("Button 16");
      JButton button17 = new JButton("Button 17");
      JButton button18 = new JButton("Button 18");

      //Add buttons to panel1
      panel1.add(button1);
      panel1.add(button2);
      panel1.add(button3);
      panel1.add(button4);
      panel1.add(button5);
      panel1.add(button6);

      //Add buttons to panel2



      //Add the buttons to panel3
      panel3.add(button7, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      panel3.add(button8, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      panel3.add(button9, BorderLayout.EAST);
      panel3.add(button10, BorderLayout.WEST);

      //Add the buttons to panel4
      panel4.add(button11);
      panel4.add(button12);
      panel4.add(button13);
      panel4.add(button14);
      panel4.add(button15);
      panel4.add(button16);
      panel4.add(button17);
      panel4.add(button18);




      // Add the five panels to the content pane.
      add(panel1, BorderLayout.WEST);
      add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(panel3, BorderLayout.EAST);
      add(panel4, BorderLayout.CENTER);



      // Pack and display the window.
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   /**
      The main method creates an instance of the
      BorderPanelWindow class, causing it to display
      its window.
   */

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      new BorderPanelWindow();
   }
}
```

Comment: I'd make that with 3 grid layouts and a border layout.  Is the area for buttons 1 through 6 the same as that for buttons 7 to 18?

Comment: I'm open to changing it however, but I was doing it with them being separate areas as I wasn't really sure how to do them being the same. Our instructor gave us very little reference information or anything to make this work so I'm very confused getting these layouts to function properly.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I just don't fully understand now what I'm doing with panel2, I know it's a gridLayout but how do I apply it?

Comment: I'm curious if you know what the arguments to GridLayout constructor actually do?

Comment: I've already said a few times I'm not really sure how any of this works and our instructor gave us very little information before he sent us to work on this.

Comment: I just can't get it, all I can ultimately end up with is panel 4 in the middle, panel 3 on the right and panel 1 on the left i cant get panel 4 in the middle of panel 3 like the image shows and I just can't figure out how to do it. I've read the documentation on the gridLayout and BorderLayout and have the tabs open right now so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: [Read The Fine Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html)

Comment: That's one of the things I was talking about having open. I've read it, multiple times, I still don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `GridLayout(rows, columns)`. You are using `3, 3`. Does your image look like 3 rows, 3 columns any where?

Comment: I see `1, 2` for the main. `2, 3` for the left. `4, 2` for the right

Comment: I'm just making sure you're saying main is for the center one, correct? When I changed it based on those numbers it makes Button 1-6 look fine and Button 7-10, but buttons 11-18 just appear all lined up in the middle but not the middle of 7-10.

Comment: Main is for the entire panel, with holds the left panel, and the right panel. The right panel as the borderlayout panel, that holds the gridlayout panel (which I mentioned above as the "right").

Comment: WHAT THE HELL IS WRONG WITH ME. 

I keep wanting to put panel 1 as 2,3 panel 2 as 4,2 and panel 4 as 1,2.

What exactly am I not understanding here with what you're telling me to do? I know this has to be simple but I feel like I've tried those numbers every which way and it's not working for me.

Comment: You are making the main panel (or frame) BorderLayout. Set it the GridLayout. That is the "main" I am talking about (the whole shabang). It should hold another GridLayout panel ("left") and a BorderLayout panel. The BordeLayout panel should have a GridLayout panel ("right") in its center. Not sure If can explain it better than that. Sorry but I don't have my IDE open to wokrk on your code

Comment: How would I put the GridLayout panel that should be Right in the center then? 

I guess what I don't understand is, do you want me to do something like this, setLayout(new BorderLayout(1,2));

or like this, JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
      panel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1,2));

Comment: Last explanation. Really. Frame = GridLayout(1, 2) -> Frame add Panel(GridLayout(2, 3) -> Frame add Panel (BorderLayout) <- this Panel add Panel(GridLayout(4, 2) to center. I don't know how much better I can explain it than that

Comment: Alright, I have this so far but now I'm confused I hope this is on track with what you were saying.

JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridLayout");
      frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
      frame.add(panel1);
      frame.add(panel3);
      frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

Answer (score 3):

I'd make that with 3 grid layouts and a border layout.  E.G.

- `GridLayout` for left/right sections (each section a panel)

  1. `GridLayout` for buttons 1-6
  2. `BorderLayout` for buttons 7-10 + panel in `CENTER` for..

     - `GridLayout` for buttons 11-18

### Update

Your edit 3 was very close, note extra comments and changes in code to see this:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;     // Needed for BorderLayout class
import javax.swing.*;  // Needed for Swing classes

/**
   This class demonstrates how JPanels can be nested
   inside each region of a content pane governed by
   a BorderLayout manager.
*/

public class BorderPanelWindow extends JFrame
{
   /**
      Constructor
   */

   public BorderPanelWindow()
   {
      // Set the title bar text.
      setTitle("Border Layout");

      // Specify an action for the close button.
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); // better

      // Add a BorderLayout manager to the content pane.
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      // Create five panels.
      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
      panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
      JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
      panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));
      JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
      panel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
      // we need as many rows as needed (0) in 2 columns (2)
      panel4.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2)); 


      // Create five buttons.
      JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
      JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
      JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
      JButton button4 = new JButton("Button 4");
      JButton button5 = new JButton("Button 5");
      JButton button6 = new JButton("Button 6");
      JButton button7 = new JButton("Button 7");
      JButton button8 = new JButton("Button 8");
      JButton button9 = new JButton("Button 9");
      JButton button10 = new JButton("Button 10");
      JButton button11 = new JButton("Button 11");
      JButton button12 = new JButton("Button 12");
      JButton button13 = new JButton("Button 13");
      JButton button14 = new JButton("Button 14");
      JButton button15 = new JButton("Button 15");
      JButton button16 = new JButton("Button 16");
      JButton button17 = new JButton("Button 17");
      JButton button18 = new JButton("Button 18");

      //Add buttons to panel1
      panel1.add(button1);
      panel1.add(button2);
      panel1.add(button3);
      panel1.add(button4);
      panel1.add(button5);
      panel1.add(button6);

      //Add buttons to panel2



      //Add the buttons to panel3
      panel3.add(button7, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      panel3.add(button8, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
      panel3.add(button9, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
      panel3.add(button10, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

      //Add the buttons to panel4
      panel4.add(button11);
      panel4.add(button12);
      panel4.add(button13);
      panel4.add(button14);
      panel4.add(button15);
      panel4.add(button16);
      panel4.add(button17);
      panel4.add(button18);

      // Add panel4 to the CENTER of panel3
      panel3.add(panel4, BorderLayout.CENTER);


      // Add the five panels to the content pane.
      add(panel1, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
      add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(panel3, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
      //add(panel4, BorderLayout.CENTER); // AND DON'T ADD IT HERE!

      // Pack and display the window.
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   /**
      The main method creates an instance of the
      BorderPanelWindow class, causing it to display
      its window.
   */

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      new BorderPanelWindow();
   }
}
```

Comment: How will I do that while still letting 1-6 appear? My idea is changing uncommenting out the add(panel10, BorderLayout.WEST); but doing that makes 1-6 disappear while putting 10 in the relatively correct place.

Comment: Show me your attempt with ***3*** grid layouts and a border layout.

Comment: I posted an answer on this thread, I'm getting closer...I hope. :D